# Admin template used by Bitbucket and Ionic Pro

Tags: templates, themes, bitbucket

Does anyone know what template library is used by Bitbucket and Ionic Pro? It looks like all classes are generated and have an "sc-" prefix.

[image: Ionic Pro Layout]

[image: Bitbucket Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Found it: https://atlassian.design/

It's a part of Atlassian's design kit that they seem to provide openly.